# How does one add exogenous data to exponential smoothing models?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Adding exogenous data as external regressors in an ARIMA model seems pretty straightforward, but how does one do so with ETS methods?

Is there a way of creating a weighted combination of the ETS forecast and a regression based on the exogenous data?

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ets-regressors/

Answer (score 1):

Some empirical studies have been done at the following papers, to create ETS models with regressors.

http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Kourentzes_2015_Promotional-modelling-with-MAPA.pdf

https://www.monash.edu/business/econometrics-and-business-statistics/research/publications/ebs/wp02-15.pdf

Comment: Please give some details, along with complete references (if your links die your answer will be almost useless). As far as possible answers should be self-contained, using links references as support for what you say in an answer rather than as an answer. See the section under "Provide context for links" in the [help on writing answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You might also find the example of quoting material from a source (and the subsequent discussion) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) helpful.